# Powershell omits CRLF output with 'out-file'

Tags: powershell

Powershell omits the CRLF when writing to a file

Repro code below

```
$part1 = "this is one line
This is a second line 
this is not
"
$part2 = "this is almost the last line
this is the last line."

$code =  $part1
$code += $part2

$code

$code  | out-file "test.cs" 
notepad test.cs
```

When I view the output in Notepad, vs the command prompt, the CRLF line breaks are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is pressing enter at the console doesn't yield a CRLF in the middle of a string only an LF. You either need to add the CRLF (`r`n) characters to your strings or build them differently. The method below simply replaces LF or CRLF sequences with CRLF. I use the `-join` operator to combine the strings.

```
$part1 = "this is one line
This is a second line 
this is not
"
$part2 = "this is almost the last line
this is the last line."

$code = -join ($part1 -replace "\r?\n","`r`n"),($part2 -replace "\r?\n","`r`n")
$code  | out-file "test.cs" 
notepad test.cs
```

You could build your variables as an array of strings. Then when accessing the objects through the pipeline, the CRLF will automatically be added to each element at output.

```
$part1 = "this is one line","This is a second line","this is not"
$part2 = "this is almost the last line","this is the last line."
$code = $part1 + $part2
$code | out-file test.cs
```

You could also use the `-split` operator to split on the LF or CRLF characters. Keep in mind that the `$part1 + $part2` only works because you have an LF at the end of `$part1`.

```
$part1 = "this is one line
This is a second line 
this is not
"
$part2 = "this is almost the last line
this is the last line."

$code = ($part1 + $part2) -split "\r?\n"
$code | out-file test.cs
```